# To what extent can a question be modified to make it easier to find?

Tags: discussion, editing

I answered the question below today and I'm thinking it would be easier to find if the title was something more generic, related to the possibility of copying multiple rotations in a symmetrical fashion or creating a logarithmic pattern. I think it's really useful knowledge but I'm worried about changing the question around too much. What are best practices?

[Mesh Fabric Design in Ai (Method and Possible way of Approaching)](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/92700/mesh-fabric-design-in-ai-method-and-possible-way-of-approaching/92705#92705)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to not changing the meaning of the post as Ryan said, we should also keep in mind a couple of things:

1. **People don't like other people changing their posts very much.** Make sure that any edits you make actually *add to the question* and *don't change the intention of the author*. If you're not sure that what you might change it to is what the OP is searching for, *leave a comment asking them* or, if no one responds, *ask in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot)*. If your edits are mostly superfluous, some people might get upset that you felt the need to edit it.
2. ***They* asked the question in that way**, which likely means that *others will ask in the same way* at least part of the time. Sometimes editing a title can really help people find a post. We want to make sure as best as we can that the title change really is more findable.

In the case you brought up in the question, I think the title change is likely a good thing.

Answer (score 6):

Edit away. As long as you don't change the meaning of the post it should be fine. In fact we've had a few people make meta posts requesting more people help to edit the question titles.